# Why do I not get a result when there is no error message?

Tags: equation-solving

I've typed in the following equation:

```
Solve[((h*s + l - r*s - r)/(s^2 + s)) (1 + s) - h == (h*s + l - r*s - r)/(s^2 + s) - r, r]
```

and it produces:

```
{}
```

without any error message. What's the reason for this?

Comment: Please read the documentation, [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html); 4th bullet, under "Details and Options", explains the return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eqn = ((h*s + l - r*s - r)/(s^2 + s)) (1 + s) - 
    h == (h*s + l - r*s - r)/(s^2 + s) - r // Simplify

(*  (h - l)/(1 + s) == 0  *)
```

Note that `r` does not appear in the simplified expression so Mathematica returns "no solution"

```
Solve[eqn, r]

(*  {}  *)
```